# Mongodump from slave only outputs 101 objects

Tags: backup, mongodb, dump

I have a mongo 1.8.3 master/slave setup. slave replication works and tests (collection sizes, query results, updates) all pass.

when i am trying to dump a collection from the slave that actually has more than a few million documents, mongodump only exports 101 objects max (that fact is applicable to all the collections on the slave).

i've read [this article in the MongoDB documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-Ifmongodumpseemstoskipdocuments...) but it's not helping out, still getting only 101 objects back.

Comment: What is the full command that you're using (omitting authentication, of course)?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may have a "nocursors" option in your mongoDB config file (or specified on the command line) - you should remove that option and your mongodump will succeed as expected.  That option limits the returned results to a single batch and would explain the issue you are seeing.  See the parameters listed here for more info:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Command+Line+Parameters

Answer (score 0):

I tested and reproduced same problem in mongodb 2.2.3. /2.0.8
If you have wrong configured firewall for mongodump then mongodump only exports 101 documents.
Try shutdown firewall or reconfigure it.